# mongoDB comparing date

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring mongoTemplate.I am trying to find Date of birth from min and max Date. My resultant query is

```
db.profile.find({ "$and" : [ { "dob" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2014-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"}}} , { "dob" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "1995-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"}}}]}).pretty()
```

but it didn't return any records.Where I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

All queries in MongoDB are **and** operations by default, so you don't need the wrapping [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) here.

It is also the wrong way to do it, your serialization should look like this:

```
{ 
    "dob" : { 
        "$lte" : { "$date" : "2014-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"},
        "$gte" : { "$date" : "1995-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"}
    }
}
```

Or basically in the shell way:

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "dob" : { 
        "$lte" : new Date("2014-01-31"),
        "$gte" : new Date("1995-01-31")
    }
})
```

So both the [**`$lte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) and [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) operations are part of the same BSON element.

Something like this with the query builder:

```
    DBObject query = new Query(
        Criteria.where("dob")
            .gte(new DateTime("1995-01-31").toDate())
            .lte(new DateTime("2014-01-31").toDate())
    ).getQueryObject();
```

Comment: I tried db.collection.find({ 
    "dob" : { 
        "$lte" : new Date("2014-01-31"),
        "$gte" : new Date("1995-01-31")
    }
}) But return no record .Sample record from DB is {"dob" : ISODate("2013-12-09T00:00:00Z")}

Comment: @PrashantThorat You did replace `collection` with your actual collection name didn't you? That would be the only reason that this would not work.

Comment: Yes thanks that works but I am interested In your first suggestion  
   db.profile.find({ "dob" : { 
        "$lte" : { "$date" : "2014-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"},
        "$gte" : { "$date" : "1995-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"}
    }})
  Its result of My Spring Mongo query returns. But I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: @PrashantThorat Was away for a bit. Added some code that works for me with spring-data

Comment: tried it in Mongo terminal { 
    "dob" : { 
        "$lte" : { "$date" : "2014-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"},
        "$gte" : { "$date" : "1995-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"}
    }
}  It gives me null result . When I remove $date and simply create new Date() then it works. Is their any problem with $date. I tried all posible date formates like joda date timeDate,util etc. but same isuue.Is this problem related with mongo.

Comment: @PrashantThorat You can't use "$date" here and that is not how I presented the code. That is just how the JavaDriver represents the serialized BSON. It is meant to be a date object just as I have done. Read the answer rather than the comments. It shows you what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I tried other answers here, but below one was worked finally.

```
db.getCollection('error_messages').find({"messageTimeStamp":{"$gte":ISODate("2008-12-03T04:45:30.000Z")}});
```